# Passing parameter using ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I used to work with `winForm`. Now I need to make a `report` using `Web`.
I Need to know how to pass `parameters` using `WebForms`. I have something but don't know how to pass it to the other page as `parameter` to the `reportviewer`

```
ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[2];
            param[0] = new ReportParameter("usr",Drop_Responsaveis.SelectedValue.ToString());
            param[1] = new ReportParameter("clube", Drop_Clientes.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Is this right ? Create the `parameters` at one page and pass it to another page that contains the `reportviewer`  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Querystring or Session to pass value to the next page. e.g. `page2.aspx?clube=1234&user=John`

Then you can retrieve the values from the querystring and pass to the report viewer

```
param[0] = new ReportParameter("usr", Request.QueryString["user"]);
param[1] = new ReportParameter("clube",  Request.QueryString["clube"]);
```

Comment: There's no other way to do that ? How would it work with sessions ? Isn't another way ? ;\ Thanks

Comment: And is not a "bad programming" create 3 `Sessions` as `parameters` ?!

Comment: Why did you need to pass it to another page? Can't you have everything in one page? However, you only have one session with which you can store as many values.